# Window scroll position when the page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know window scroll position when a page is fully loaded.

When I click on a link with id, page is loaded according to element with this id.When page is loaded, I would like to know window position.

**index.html**

```
<a href="page.html#2012_8">link</a>
```

**page.html**

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
</script>

<p id="2012_8">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

When I click on link, console log get 0. When I refresh page.html, console log get correct window scroll position. Why? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Fiddle to demo the behavior: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2bL7X/show/. Clicking "Go!" should send you the hash marker `foobar` of a different fiddle, and you should see a popup with "load 5027" or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using

`console.log($(document).scrollTop());`

I tested in firebug and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The 'load' event is not triggering when you change the window hash.  To get the event to fire you should hook into the hashchange event.

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function() {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: Does this apply here? The OP is navigating to a *completely different page* (`index.html` -> `page.html`) that has a hash.

Comment: @apsillers didn't see that!  Thanks.  This solution should still work on a different page. But doesn't answer the question at all!

Comment: @Bluetoft Exactly, this is not answer to my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($(document).prop('scrollHeight'));
})
```

or you can use attr for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($(document).attr('scrollHeight'));
})
```

Comment: -1: [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight) measures the height of an element's total scrollable content. It does not change based on scrolling; it changes when the content contained inside the element increases or decreases in height. The OP wants the scroll offset, i.e., how far down the page is *currently scrolled*.